# Unable to use internet, but settings shows Ethernet as connected

Tags: network, macos

I recently went through setting up a new DHCP server. It's working, except for my Mac. Renewing the DHCP lease doesn't get it an IP address and if I assign a manual IP address, settings app shows **Ethernet is connected but safari and chrome don't connect to any sites**, not even my router or server's configuration page. I've tried restarting and resetting the network config to no avail. I'm running **macOS 10.12.6**

Comment: What is the IP address that dhcp gave you? and do other machines see the internet?

Comment: What IP address does he DHCP server give other devices (you said it was working; I assume you have other devices on the network).  Can you ping that device from your Mac?